# How to alternate between three texts being displayed on the same place with transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have three rows with the component Typography. I want to show the first row, then alternate to the second, then the third, and then back to the first one.

They should be displayed on the same place, and only one at a time.

```
<Typography>Welcome.</Typography> 
<Typography>Willkommen.</Typography>  
<Typography>Bem-vindo.</Typography>
```

Comment: See [the `useSpring` hook](https://react-spring.io/hooks/use-spring)

Comment: Oh I'll definitely check out useSpring! Didn't know about it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Which = () => {
  const [which, setWhich] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setWhich(state => (state < 3 ? state + 1 : 1));
        }, 3000);
    }, []);

  return (
        <div>
            {
                which === 1 &&
                <div>Welcome</div>
            }
            {
                which === 2 &&
                <div>Willkommen</div>
            }
            {
                which === 3 &&
                 <div>Bem-vindo</div>
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks davood. useEffect and useState make this so much easier. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If you got the answer please accept my answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just tested at work and it worked! I had to make an adjustment though. Inside the useEffect I had to include the "which" (the state) dependency inside the [ ] so it updates correctly.  

like so:  

  useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setWhich(state => (state < 3 ? state + 1 : 1));
        }, 3000);
    }, [which]);  

Now I'll go to css to see if I can add a smooth transition.